# Azure Terraform: No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date but resources are not created and terraform Destroy - command fails

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-load-balancer

When I execute

```
 terraform plan -var-file="parms.tfvars" -out="stageplan.out"
```

The code says that the infrastructure is up-to-date but when I go into Azure load balancers everything underneath rules doesn't work. Here's the code that doesn't get deployed:

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  name                = "weblb"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"  
  sku                 = "${var.lb_sku}"

   frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "webfrontend"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.web_tier.id}"
    private_ip_address            = "${var.frontend_private_ip_address}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.frontend_private_ip_address_allocation}"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_pool" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "webBackendPool"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "azlb" {
  count                          = "${length(var.remote_port)}"
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                           = "VM-${count.index}"
  protocol                       = "tcp"
  frontend_port                  = "5000${count.index + 1}"
  backend_port                   = "${element(var.remote_port["${element(keys(var.remote_port), count.index)}"], 1)}"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${var.frontend_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "azlb" {
  count               = "${length(var.lb_port)}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"
  protocol            = "${element(var.lb_port["${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"], 1)}"
  port                = "${element(var.lb_port["${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"], 2)}"
  interval_in_seconds = "${var.lb_probe_interval}"
  number_of_probes    = "${var.lb_probe_unhealthy_threshold}"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "azlb" {
  count                          = "${length(var.lb_port)}"
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                           = "${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"
  protocol                       = "${element(var.lb_port["${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"], 1)}"
  frontend_port                  = "${element(var.lb_port["${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"], 0)}"
  backend_port                   = "${element(var.lb_port["${element(keys(var.lb_port), count.index)}"], 2)}"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${var.frontend_name}"
  enable_floating_ip             = false
  backend_address_pool_id        = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool.id}"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes        = 5
  probe_id                       = "${element(azurerm_lb_probe.azlb.*.id,count.index)}"
  depends_on                     = ["azurerm_lb_probe.azlb"]
}
```

Even before I tried to implement the load balancer section, my code executed without any errors. Now when I try to execute terraform destroy. I get the following error message listed below.

> C:\Users\sna1> terraform destroy 7 error(s) occurred:
>
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[0]: expected storage_data_disk.0.managed_disk_type to be one of [Premium_LRS
>     Standard_LRS StandardSSD_LRS], got
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[0]: expected storage_os_disk.0.managed_disk_type to be one of [Premium_LRS
>     Standard_LRS StandardSSD_LRS], got
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[0]: storage_data_disk.0.disk_size_gb: cannot parse '' as int:
>     strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[1]: expected storage_data_disk.0.managed_disk_type to be one of [Premium_LRS
>     Standard_LRS StandardSSD_LRS], got
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[1]: expected storage_os_disk.0.managed_disk_type to be one of [Premium_LRS
>     Standard_LRS StandardSSD_LRS], got
> - azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-with-datadisk[1]: storage_data_disk.0.disk_size_gb: cannot parse '' as int:
>     strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax
> - azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: "address_space.0" must not be empty

Comment: could you try to remove the state file and run the terraform init->plan->apply again?

Comment: tried and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Try to `terraform destroy -var-file="parms.tfvars"`? You should add the variable files when destroying in your case.

Comment: Hi, any update on your question?